# When Patti Smith describes getting onto a 'Jefferson Airplane' plane/van on Atlantic Avenue is she using realism, metaphor, analogy, or other trope?

Tags: untagged

In a chapter entitled 'In Search of Imaginos' in her book 'Year of the Monkey', Patti Smith describes herself walking down Atlantic Avenue (presumably in [Brooklyn, NY](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Atlantic+Ave,+New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.6760971,-73.906549,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c25c3f38e81363:0xa9229ba9cdb924e3!8m2!3d40.6760971!4d-73.9043603)).

She writes:

> [I] walked up the metal ramp, took my seat on the *Jefferson Airplane*. The plane, not the band, but when I looked out, I realized I was in a van, not a plane, which was thoroughly confusing. The driver turned on the radio, a baseball game interrupted by radio calls in another language, somewhat musical, maybe Albanian. He took a different route than I requested and ignored any questions. ... We were gridlocked on a bridge, only it was not a usual bridge and seemed to be slightly swaying. I was more than tempted to get out and cross on foot.

Previously, she has picked up a coat (presumably for sale, but that she hasn't paid for), found a rubber band in the pocket, following which she fastens her hair in a pony tail. Whether she uses the rubber band to do that is unclear.

Culturally, I'm unfamiliar with the references although I'm aware that [Jefferson Airplane](https://medium.com/cuepoint/patti-smith-jefferson-airplane-ushered-us-through-the-summer-of-love-614348cc7e46) was a 60s rock band, and a bridge might either be a [guitar bridge](https://www.guitarlobby.com/guitar-bridge-types/) or a reference to either Brooklyn bridge or Manhattan bridge.

The chapter not only references Sandy Pearlman's *[Imaginos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginos)* in the title, but has an epigraph from one of his works.

Does Patti get on a plane, into a van, or a taxi? Is she deliberately evoking a hyper-real dream-state in her writing here? Or should we take her literally? Maybe both? Maybe neither? How do you see this?